# How to insert a string in an empty font tag?

Tags: php

how can I add a string in an empty font tag? Like if in the second font tag there is no value, I will just insert a `<br />` tag. How can I do that?

I have this HTML code:

```
<P ALIGN="LEFT">
    <FONT FACE="Verdana" style="font-size:10" COLOR="#0B333C" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">
        Welcome to jQuery Course
    </FONT>
</P>
<P ALIGN="LEFT">
    <FONT FACE="Verdana" style="font-size:10" COLOR="#0B333C" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">
    </FONT>
</P>
<P ALIGN="LEFT">
    <FONT FACE="Verdana" style="font-size:10" COLOR="#0B333C" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">
        This is the jQuery Introduction content.
    </FONT>
</P>
```

And I like the output to be:

```
<P ALIGN="LEFT">
        <FONT FACE="Verdana" style="font-size:10" COLOR="#0B333C" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">
            Welcome to jQuery Course
        </FONT>
    </P>
    <P ALIGN="LEFT">
        <FONT FACE="Verdana" style="font-size:10" COLOR="#0B333C" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">
            <br />
        </FONT>
    </P>
    <P ALIGN="LEFT">
        <FONT FACE="Verdana" style="font-size:10" COLOR="#0B333C" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">
            This is the jQuery Introduction content.
        </FONT>
    </P>
```

Comment: Could you provide example output, too?

Comment: Are you wanting to do this in PHP, or jQuery? Your question references PHP, the html references jQuery and contains no PHP...

Comment: hi soulmerge and paul, I edited my post and included the sample output. I need to do this in PHP first but if there is a much better solution in jQuery then why not :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a font tag.

You can

```
str_replace("></FONT>", ">$myinserttext</FONT>", $myhtml);
```

in PHP or

```
$("font:empty").html("Sample Content");
```

in jQuery.

Comment: Thanks antony. I will try both of your solutions :D

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
$("font:empty").html("My string");

or append:

$("font:empty").append("My string");
```